# How do I display names with apostrophes in sp using sql server

Tags: sql-server

When I am Passing Simple names without apostrophe am getting output but when i am passing names with apostrophe it is showing error
Sample Input and output-

```
Exec Getnames 'Jeremy  Alford'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RI9Pz.jpg)

```
Exec Getnames 'Thomas D'' Chen'
```

the error is :

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'Chen'.
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ') order by name'.
```

This is my table

[Table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBQD6.jpg)

This is my Stored Procedure

```
Alter PROCEDURE Getnames
@Clientname VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX)
set @Clientname= Replace(@Clientname,',',''',''')
Set @Sql='Select name from NewAddData3 where   Name IN('''+@Clientname+''')'  
exec (@Sql)
Go
```

Comment: Exec Getnames 'Thomas D'''' Chen' - Try to use PRINT function to give you hints. This would help you alot.

Comment: Use data types *designed* to hold multiple values (here, `@Clientname` should be a *table-valued parameter*) and *maintain* proper parameterization (e.g. use `sp_executesql` **if** dynamic SQL is required, it isn't here) and you avoid all kinds of issues that you're *causing yourself* by trying to hold multiple values in a string.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the replace,

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE Getnames
    @Clientname VARCHAR(MAX)
    AS
    DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX)
    Set @Sql='Select name from NewAddData3 where   Name IN( '''+ @Clientname +''')'  
            exec (@Sql)
    Go
```

Then you can run `exec Getnames 'Thomas D'' Chen'` without exception

Comment: It Didn't work and what do you mean by 'without exception'.

Answer (score 0):

better to use sp_executesql

```
Alter PROCEDURE Getnames
@Clientname VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX)
-- set @Clientname= Replace(@Clientname,',',''',''')
Set @Sql='Select name from NewAddData3 where   Name IN ( @Clientname )'  
exec sp_executesql @Sql, N'@Clientname varchar(max)', @Clientname 
Go
```

Comment: Not a total fix - in case it's not clear form the `REPLACE`, they're clearly trying to pass *multiple* names here in that single string parameter, and now tying themselves in knots and using dynamic SQL because of that initial mistake.

Comment: Can't we do without using sp_executesql ?

Comment: why ? what is your consideration ?

Answer (score 0):

Exec Getnames 'Thomas D'''' Chen'

This work for me

```
Alter PROCEDURE Getnames
@Clientname VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX)
Set @Sql='Select name from NewAddData3 where   Name IN('''+@Clientname+''')'  
print @Sql
exec (@Sql)
Go
```